# Return pandas.DataFrame when slice has one row result

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2), index=[100, 101, 101, 102, 103])
>>> idx = set(df.index)
>>> for id_ in idx:
...     slice = df.loc[id_]
...     # stuff with slice
>>>
```

I need to do stuff with `slice` within the `for` loop but that stuff is predicated on `slice` being a `DataFrame`. `slice` is a `DataFrame` when there are more than one matching records, but a `Series` otherwise. I know `pandas.Series` has the `Series.to_frame` method but `pandas.DataFrame` does not (so I cannot just call `df.loc[id_].to_frame()`).

What is the best way to test and coerce `slice` into a `DataFrame`?

(Is it really as simple as testing if `isinstance(df.loc[id_], pd.Series)`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) object by index (`level=0`):

```
for i, df1 in df.groupby(level=0):
    print (df1)

            0         1
100 -0.812375 -0.450793
            0         1
101  1.070801  0.217421
101 -1.175859 -0.926117
            0         1
102 -0.993948  0.586806
            0         1
103  1.063813  0.237741
```

Your solution should be changed by selecting double `[]` for return `DataFrame`:

```
idx = set(df.index)
for id_ in idx:
    df1 = df.loc[[id_]]
    print (df1)

            0         1
100 -0.775057 -0.979104
            0         1
101 -1.549363 -1.206828
101  0.445008 -0.173086
            0        1
102  1.488947 -0.79252
            0         1
103  1.838997 -0.439362
```

Comment: Why does the internal list work (i.e. turning `id_` into `[id_]`)?

Comment: @JasonStrimpel - Not sure if understand, but pandas working `df.loc[[id_]]` like selecting one list value, similar solution is if need select multiple values of list like `df.loc[[id1, id2]]`

Answer (score 1):

Or use `df[...]` conditioning `df.index`:

```
...
for id_ in idx:
     slice = df[df.index==id_]
     print(slice)
```

Output:

```
            0         1
100  2.751189  1.978744
            0         1
101  0.154483  1.646657
101  1.381725  0.982819
           0         1
102  0.26669  0.032702
            0         1
103  0.186235 -0.481184
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force the variable slice to be a pandas dataframe by using the pd.Dataframe init method as follows:

```
for id_ in idx:
    slice = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[id_])
    print(type(slice))
```

output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Then you can treat the variables as Dataframes inside the loop.